properly getting access to templater object in an obsidian quickadd plugin
I am creating a user script for use in a QuickAdd plugin Macro in Obsidian. The Macro has a single step and simply runs the user script (JavaScript that uses the CommonJS standard). One of the steps in the user script is to create a new note in Obsidian with a Templater template. The problem I'm having is the script cannot access the templater.current_functions_object unless I manually create a new note with a Templater template first. I am guessing it gets loaded into memory after it is manually executed one time. I would like to run my Macro and have it automatically create the new note with a Templater template without the need for the manual step if possible.
Q: Is there a way to make sure the templater.current_functions_object is avaiable in the user script without a need to manually create a new note with a Templater template first?
I created a simple test script below help figure this out.
When I run a test Macro with the following user script, I get 'Unable to access the tp current functions object.' with a fresh launch of Obsidian. If I manually create a new note in Obsidian with a Templater template, run the test Macro again, then it works and I get 'Found the tp current functions object!'. I'm attempting to run this without requiring the manual step.
am expecting answers to how quickadd plugin is used in obsidian
